# Проблема с preg_match_all

Tags: php

Вот кусок с кода:

```
preg_match_all('/<body[^>]*>(.*)<\/body>/', str_replace("\n", '', $str), $out);
```

Функция должна парсить от тэга `<body>` до `</body>`

Я хочу заменить, чтобы функция парсила от тэга `<img src="115" h="14" w="14" />` до тэга `<br />`

Но у меня не получается - уже всю голову сломал.. Помогите пожалуйста, скажу спасибо;)

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match_all('/<img.*?\/>(.*?)<br\s*\/>/is', $str, $out);
```

как то так